# Does sonarqube show cyclomatic complexity of a method?

Tags: sonarqube

Apart from displaying complexity/function, can it be configured to display cyclomatic complexity of each method? This will help in quickly identifying potential refactoring candidates( methods) in large files with large number of methods.

Answer (score 7):

Sadly, SonarQube does not fully support method-level metrics.

However, you could give CodeAnalyzer plug-in a try: http://frontendart.com/products/codeanalyzer-for-sonarqube/

McCabe's Cyclomatic Complexity is the metric your are looking for, I believe. I found an online demo for the plug-in (http://sonarqube.frontendart.com/), which does contain method-level McCC metric values.

I hope this helps,
John

Answer (score 1):

To fulfill your needs, you should activate rules such as http://nemo.sonarqube.org/rules_configuration/index/7?sort_by=SORT_BY_RULE_NAME&searchtext=Methods+should+not+be+too+complex&rule_activation=ACTIVE&inheritance=any&commit=Search. Then, you'll be able to quickly access those complex methods.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have configured the right rules (see the answer from @David RACODON) you can find complexity of method in the GUI in (at least) two different places.

If you drill down from Dashboard to Major Issues, you'll find "Avoid too complex method" listed.  Select it, and you'll see a report of methods to review.

Another path to that information is to select one of the complexity measures from the dashboard, for example Complexity/class.  That shows you a listing of classes in complexity order.  Select one, and the source is displayed, along with some links and metadata.  Select the "issues" link, and you can select "Avoid too complex method" from a dropdown.

NB: We are running Sonar 4.0, other releases may be somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to see the complexity of a method.
The only thing I found is averaged complexity (per class or per method), which is fundamentally wrong since there is no evidence that software metrics (such as complexity) have a central tendency. Evidence shows that that software metrics follow power-law like distributions.